# C# Entity Framework 6 - select columns with

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have table A with many-to-many connection to another table B. The object A contains list of objects B.

I want to select only 1 columns from B to create object A with all columns of A table and a list of B objects with value in 1 property (and the rest are null).

I tried this code:

```
dbContext.A.Include(a => a.B.select(b => b.property))
```

But it throws an error:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType does not declare a navigation property with the name *

Comment: and B is your joining table or?

Comment: It looks like you don't have a relationship between the tables. Include would be used for a relationship. In this case you'd want to use a LINQ JOIN.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join

Comment: Do this in DTOs. You shouldn't partly populate entities and EF doesn't have any facility to do that.